# Where are screenshots taken with the SWTOR holocamera saved?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I purchased the digital plus pack for SWTOR and received the Holocamera.

This should take screenshots (and seems to).

I cannot figure out where these screenshots are store or if they actually are, or it is just a gimmick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are located under My Documents. This can be confusing to get to in Windows 7 because My Documents is not the same as your Documents library (go figure). You can typically find this in `C:/Users/Username/My Documents` under a SWTOR folder.

Comment: On my Win7, the My Documents folder is actually part of the Documents library. Also, I don't have any holocamera, but PrintScreen works for me.

Comment: I had to add My Documents to my Documents library. It's possible I removed it a while back and forgot but who knows.

Comment: The holocam is functionally the same as hiding the ui (ctrl+z), zooming in all the way to first-person (scroll wheel) and taking a printscreen. It's certainly convenient, though.